# How do I attach an instance-specific queryset to a model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset, django-managers

I am making a very minimal user-to-user messaging app using Django 1.4. I want to fetch unread messages that a user received in a straightforward way from my templates. My model looks something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_sent')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_received')
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I can easily access the messages that a user has received from `user.messages_received`. I'd like to filter this queryset, though, to quickly access the unread messages in an easy way. I know that I can always filter the queryset `user.messages_received.filter(read=False)`, but I'd like to get at them directly in templates, possibly like this:

```
<a href="{% url inbox %}"> Inbox ({{ user.unread_messages.count }})</a>
```

I suspect I want to make a Manager, but I'm not sure how to write it or where to attach it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this that come to my mind.

First, you could extend the user model with a **custom function**.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def unread_messages(self):
    return self.messages_received.filter(read=False)
User.add_to_class('unread_messages', unread_messages)
```

But that is slightly hacky. The "clean" way would be not to extend the User model directly, but to **create a UserProfile** for your users and add the function there. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) describe this quite well.

In your case:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def unread_messages(self):
        return self.user.messages_received.filter(read=False)
```

*settings.py*

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'appname.UserProfile'
```

*template*

```
{{ user.get_profile.unread_messages.count }}
```

The code is untested, but should work :)

Comment: Thanks, I can easily add that to my user profile model. I'm a little hesitant, though. My profile model is in a different app than my message app, and I was hoping not to mix the two. But this certainly works.

Comment: You could also solve it via a custom template filter that gets the count for a user passed as the parameter. But I'm not sure whether that's a cleaner solution, probably not :)

Comment: And if you decorate ``unread_messages`` with ``@property``, you do no longer need ``()`` for calling it and it will look a lot as if it were in fact a Manager.